# Django retrieval of list of files in S3 bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I am currently working with the way django interacts with S3. I have found the boto library helpful, but was interested in creating a function to return the name of the list of files inside a particular bucket, so I can loop through and download only a portion of them passing through a specific directory.

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

def get_s3_filename_list(directory):

    bucket_name = AWS_BUCKET_NAME

    conn = boto.connect_s3(
        KEY_ID,
        ACCESS_KEY
    )

    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    key = bucket.get_key(directory)
```

However, the key that gets returns in None. 
Was wondering if anyone had experience getting list of file names.

Any advice or links would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: use `bucket.list` as in answer, but pass `directory` in. Like this: `for key in bucket.list(directory): print key.name`.

Comment: Thanks! This combined with the answer below worked amazingly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(settings.MEDIA_BUCKET)

for key in bucket.list():
    print key.name
```

Comment: This pulls from the entire bucket, and not from a particular directory within that bucket. Would this work to pass through a directory name instead?

Comment: thanks! yes- i saw that! answers combined were both VERY helpful