# List all static assets in Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to list all static assets from views. One way is to use absolute path but is there a Django way of doing it? Another way I tried using was `request.build_absolute_uri()`, but `os.listdir()` cannot open it as it's a URL.

Any suggestions?

I serve my files through S3.

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) from settings:

```
from django.conf import settings

for folder in settings.STATICFILES_DIRS:
    # do whatever you want here
```

But that would only work if you use `runserver`. If you use `collectstatic` and your web server to deliver static files, you should go with:

```
from django.conf import settings

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(settings.STATIC_ROOT):
    # do whatever you want here
```

Comment: Will this work if I linked all my static assets to S3?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used S3, so I can't tell you anything substantial.

Comment: Update: maybe, this question can help (note: it uses an additional package, if that is important to you): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933834/django-retrieval-of-list-of-files-in-s3-bucket